# Linksys and HotSpot

Tags: router, hotspot

The HotSpot does not have the strong signal of the Linksys router throughout the house. Can one use the Linksys Router to amplify the HotSpot signal in the house?

Comment: Yes. Linksys calls it `Repeater Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is called wireless Bridge Mode (or Repeater Mode, as @week points out) and means instead of acting as a proper router, your Linksys will just repeat the signal of the HotSpot.